How to manage that escapes for the double quotes `'\"'` inside the 'user content' for training datasets will not be removed?
1. Objective
The objective is to ensure the training data keeps the needed format for a model training.
Using the SFTTrainer model training. The SFTTrainer has a parameter train_dataset=dataset, that expects a dict as an input for the training.
The training data contains a before it will be converted to a dict, a JSON format which includes a JSON array where one JSON value pair contains an markup language as text and this markup language text contains text that which represents JSON.
Here is an example of the data input format before it is loaded in the datasets library, which converts the complex JSON to a dict.
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "my instructions"}, {"role": "user", "content": "my question"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "```json\n{\"key\":\"mykey\",\"value\":\"myvalue\"}"\n```}"]}

During the conversion to a dict, it removes the escapes from the original data, which impacts the model's answers not in the expected format later, as you can see this in the situation section of the issue.
{'messages': [{'role': 'system', 'content': 'my instructions'},
{'role': 'user', 'content': 'my question'}, 
{'role': 'assistant', 'content': '```json\n{"key": "mykey", "value": "myvalue" }"\n```}']

2. Situation
I noticed this behaviour after the finetuning of a model using the training data. The answer of a the finetuned model to a question didn't contain the right format, inside a complex answer json.
Answer format of the model later, if the nested json text is not escaped with "\"" the answer json can't be parsed and needs additional effort to extract the content of value for the "key_nested_json_as_text":"value".
Answer format of the model later should be like this:
{ 
  "key_one" : "value_one",
  "key_nested_json_as_text" : "```json\n{\"key\":\"mykey\",\"value\":\"myvalue\"}\n```"
}

This format can't be parse using JSON:
{ 
  "key_one" : "value_one",
  "key_nested_json_as_text" : "```json\n{"key":"mykey","value":"myvalue"}\n```"
}

The "key_nested_json_as_text":"value" cause the problem later:
```json\n{\"key\":\"mykey\",\"value\":\"myvalue\"}"\n```

3. To Reproduce problem situation
The function load_dataset from huggingface datasets removes the escapes before the double quotes '"' inside the user content for the training datasets should not be removed by the datasets library.

Here is an example of the training data input format for the json file:

"{\"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "my instructions"}, {"role": "user", "content": "my question"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "```json\n{\"key\":\"mykey\",\"value\":\"myvalue\"}"\n```}]}"


This is how I use the load_dataset function:

load_dataset('json', data_files='my_input_file.json', field='messages', split="train")


That is how I display the result using print of the content:

for data in train_dataset:
    print(f"\n{data}")

The resulting format in datasets output is:
{'messages': [{'role': 'system', 'content': 'my instructions'}, {'role": 'user', 'content': 'my question'}, {'role": 'assistant', 'content': '```json\n{"key": "mykey", "value": "myvalue"}\n```'}]}

But I like to ensure that the escapes for the double quotes '"' inside the user content will not be removed by the datasets library.

I want to have this format for the training

'```json\n{\"key\": \"mykey\", \"value\": \"myvalue\"}\n```'


and not this is used.

'```json\n{"key": "mykey", "value": "myvalue"}\n```'

Any idea, if there is someone who had the same situation and has a solution that would be awesome?

import json; print(f"\n{json.dumps(data)}") — There's your backslashes back…

@deceze
Your feedback doesn't help in this case, I added additional information of the needed resulting format in the answer later:
  "key_one" : "value_one",
  "key_nested_json_as_text" : "```json\n{\"key\":\"mykey\",\"value\":\"myvalue\"}"\n```"
}```
 
There is no isolated `print(f"\n{json.dumps(data)}")` without additional extraction effort for the give answer possible.

but again, thanks for your time, and trying to provide feedback.

When looking at {'messages': [{'role': 'syste..., you look at the string representation of a dictionary. That's not a JSON any more, the only way you could have got there is parsing the JSON. If you didn't parse it, you would have what you wanted. Whatever that is.

Note that your "This format can't be parse using JSON" and "The resulting format in datasets output is" are different. The former is indeed invalid in any language due to the double quotes within double quotes. The latter is an almost valid Python dict (some quote typos in there?!). It would turn into your "should be like this" format if you JSON-encoded it.

@tevemadar ...  That is right. Later, the model answer for the key "key_nested_json_as_text" contains markup JSON text. This text value will be extracted, isolated, and used later as a JSON.
This situation could be seen using JSON to transport hidden JSON content for later usage. The challenge is that the '"' will be removed when the training messages are converted to a dict, this leads to the wrong responses later of the model.

Likely you are simply treating the data incorrectly somewhere, which leads to it not being parsable. There is no problem per se in the data you show. I've posted an answer below explaining why. You're barking up the wrong tree.

How did you suddenly get from {'messages': [{'role': ... after loading the dataset to { "key_one": ... ("the format that can't be parsed")?! The former is a Python dict, where the backslashes aren't necessary. The latter looks like JSON again, but incorrectly escaped JSON. If a Python dict turned into an incorrectly escaped JSON string again, then something's wrong the process that does that.

This is JSON:
{ 
  "key_one" : "value_one",
  "key_nested_json_as_text" : "```json\n{\"key\":\"mykey\",\"value\":\"myvalue\"}\n```"
}

It is a structured text format describing different kinds of values. This particular JSON sample describes an object with two properties: "key_one" and "key_nested_json_as_text". The key_nested_json_as_text property has a value which is a string, which describes the following text:
```json
{"key":"mykey","value":"myvalue"}
```

This is crucial to understand. The JSON format with the backslashes and all describes the above textual content. When a proper JSON parser parses that JSON file, the semantic result of that will be the above text. The text does not contain backslashes or newline escape sequences (\n). Those were not part of the text, they were only needed in the JSON serialisation format.
Why were they needed? Because JSON delimits all strings with double quote characters ("). Any double quote character within this JSON string literal must be escaped, else it would be interpreted as the JSON string delimiter.
"```json\n{\"key\":\"mykey\",\"value\":\"myvalue\"}\n```"
^       ^^ ^^   ^^ ^^     ^^ ^^     ^^ ^^       ^^ ^^   ^
|                                                       |
delimiter                                       delimiter

All the ^^ character sequences are escape sequences, only the two " at the start and end are actual double quotes, serving as delimiters. The backslashes and \n sequences only exist because the JSON format does not allow double quotes or newlines to exists without them. You do not want them to be part of your actual text content and they aren't part of the actual text content, they're only needed to express this text content in JSON.

Now, when you parse your initial JSON using Python, what you get is a Python dict with keys and values, which contain the semantic text content that the JSON described. When you print this Python dict, you'll get a Python literal representation, which looks like:
{'key_one': 'value_one', 'key_nested_json_as_text': '```json\n{"key":"mykey","value":"myvalue"}\n```'}

This is not your original value in your JSON file, even though it looks very similar. Python dicts and JSON objects use a very similar syntax, but they're entirely unrelated. The primary clue here are the quotes: JSON requires double quotes ("), Python dict literals can use ' or ", and Python prefers single quotes by default.
So you're looking at a Python dict with two keys: key_one and key_nested_json_as_text, and the key_nested_json_as_text value is:
```json
{"key":"mykey","value":"myvalue"}
```

It expresses the exact same value as your original JSON file did. And this nested value parses perfectly fine as valid JSON, if you strip the pre- and postfix from it:
>>> d
{'key_one': 'value_one', 'key_nested_json_as_text': '```json\n{"key":"mykey","value":"myvalue"}\n```'}

>>> j = d['key_nested_json_as_text']
>>> j
'```json\n{"key":"mykey","value":"myvalue"}\n```'

>>> print(j)
```json
{"key":"mykey","value":"myvalue"}
```

>>> j.split('\n')
['```json', '{"key":"mykey","value":"myvalue"}', '```']

>>> j.split('\n')[1]
'{"key":"mykey","value":"myvalue"}'

>>> json.loads(j.split('\n')[1])
{'key': 'mykey', 'value': 'myvalue'}


Thanks for your detailed feedback.
As I understand your feedback is not to ensure the training data has the right format:
"{\"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "my instructions"}, {"role": "user", "content": "my question"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "```json\n{\"key\":\"mykey\",\"value\":\"myvalue\"}"\n```}]}"
You are talking about how to handle the answer of the trained model with the "wrong" format.
{    "key_one" : "value_one",   "key_nested_json_as_text" : "```json\n{"key":"mykey","value":"myvalue"}\n```" } That is also a valid point of view.

I'm telling you that your idea of "right" and "wrong format" is wrong.

You are right it depends on the perspective. That is not a wrong format is it only useful for me it the context I want to use it.

It’s not a matter of perspective. It’s a matter of what content you want to express and the necessities of the format you want to express it in. The content and its meaning come first, the correct way to express it in your target format follows automatically and isn’t a choice nor preference.
